# Powershell get-eventlog fails after KB4565503

Tags: powershell, script

On a home network, a desktop has read the eventlog of a laptop up to 2020-06-30. The first time since then I ran the script I got

> get-eventlog : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

This behavior also occurs in administrator mode.

Both the desktop & the laptop were updated with KB4565503. That update says it included a bunch of security updates. Okay, but what do I need to do to get the script to run?

get-errors.ps1:

```
Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$startDate
)

$after = Get-Date -Date $startDate

Write-Host "Getting power data"
$power = get-eventlog -computername geolaptop -log System -instanceid (1,42) -after $after | where-object {$_.Source -eq "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" -or $_.Source -eq "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter"}

Write-Host "Create power CSV file"
$power | select-object "eventid", "timegenerated" |export-csv power.csv

Write-Host "Getting error data"
$errors = get-eventlog -computername geolaptop -log System -instanceid (17) -after $after

Write-Host "Create errors CSV file"
$errors | select-object "timegenerated" |export-csv errors.csv

Write-Host "Populate MySQL tables"
.\sessions
```

Comment: That err msg is pretty specific. What did you search for that? Point of note: Write-Host is never needed for general output to the screen, that is the PowerShell default. Write-Host is only really needed in a few cases: [1:] Screen output in color and [2:] in some string formatting use cases. Lastly, Get-Event-Log is depreciated, and you should be using Get-WinEvent

Answer (score 0):

Following up with my comment:

This is really not a PowerShell issue but and environment one base on your error. Be it because of the update, which we cannot help with troubleshooting unless one has encountered that. Similar to the data seen from the search below.

['get-eventlog : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27get-eventlog%20%3A%20Attempted%20to%20perform%20an%20unauthorized%20operation%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=d67e870d3b4749c9b802e8462148b7d0&sp=-1&pq=%27get-eventlog%20%3A%20attempted%20to%20perform%20an%20unauthorized%20operation%27&sc=0-63&qs=n&sk=&cvid=d67e870d3b4749c9b802e8462148b7d0)

Why are you doing this?

```
$after = Get-Date -Date $startDate
```

This is just assigning the StartDate to a new variable then using the new variable later, vs just using the original variable, which makes one or the other redundant.

```
# Refactored code using Get-WinEvent instead

$StartDate = (Get-Date)

'power','error' | 
ForEach {
    switch ($PSItem) 
    { 
        power 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 1, 42
                StartTime   = $StartDate
            } | 
            Select-Object -Property LogName, TimeCreated, Id, Level | 
            Export-Csv -Path "D:\Temp\$($PSItem)Report.Csv"   
        } 
        error 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 17
                StartTime   = $StartDate
            } | 
            Select-Object -Property LogName, TimeCreated, Id, Level | 
            Export-Csv -Path "D:\Temp\$($PSItem)Report.Csv"         
        } 
        default {Write-Warning -Message 'No records which meet the criteria provided.'}
    }
}
# Results
<#
Getting power data
Getting error data
#>

'power','error' | 
ForEach {
    "`nShowing report for System log $PSItem data"
    Import-Csv -Path "D:\Temp\$($PSItem)Report.Csv"
}
# Results
<#
Showing report for System log power data

LogName TimeCreated        Id Level
------- -----------        -- -----
System  03-Aug-20 13:44:49 1  4    
System  03-Aug-20 13:44:42 1  4    
System  03-Aug-20 01:53:27 42 4    

Showing report for System log error data
System  01-Aug-20 15:13:27 17 4    
System  01-Aug-20 15:13:21 17 4    
System  01-Aug-20 15:13:20 17 4 
#>
```

What is this doing, and why is it part of your post?
There is no context of this to what data set your posted query.

```
'Populate MySQL tables'
.\sessions
```

Comment: While your critique may turn out to be useful it does not answer the question. The script is a first-time effort that worked. Its objective is to provide a CSV file to a PHP script (`sessions.php)`. That script loads the data into a MySQL database. I then import that data to an Excel pivot table. The pivot table now contains months worth of data on corrected hardware errors.

Comment: This was not a critique, but an observation based on your query and another option to try. That [sessions], as noted has zero context, so was not relevant to your issue. BTW, you can do the sessions use case directly in PowerShell to MySql as well as direct interaction with Excel for that pivot table via the Excel DOM/COM. The fact that the script fails after an update, means the environment changed. If you OS restore back to a previous data and things work, and update and things fail, you have your root cause. Thus, what in that update is changing your environment. Only you can address that.

Comment: I have this same KB on all my systems,    

[ Get-HotFix -Id KB4565503

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn               
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------               
Lab001        Update           KB4565503     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  15-Jul-20 00:00:00 ]

and your code post as is or mine, both work. Tested on Win8/WIn10/Server 2K8 - 2k19 as a normal user and local admin. So, again, points to an environmental change on your side.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between answers here is the use of `Get-WinEvent`, which did not generate the failure. Credit for that has been given to @postanote. Below is my adaptation of postanote's answer.

```
# Include quoted greatest date (e.g., '2020-06-30') from db as command line parameter

Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$startDate
)

$after = Get-Date -Date $startDate
# after is now an object

'power','error' | 
ForEach {
    switch ($PSItem) 
    { 
        power 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'geolaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 1, 42
                StartTime   = $after
            } | 
            # restrict properties to only those required
            Select-Object -Property Id, TimeCreated | 
            Export-Csv -Path "$($PSItem).Csv"   
        } 
        error 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'geolaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 17
                StartTime   = $after
            } | 
            # restrict properties to only those required
            Select-Object -Property TimeCreated | 
            Export-Csv -Path "$($PSItem).Csv"         
        } 
        default {Write-Warning -Message 'No records which meet the criteria provided.'}
    }
}

"Populate MySQL tables"
.\sessions
```

Comment: Glad it got you moving forward. Maybe these are of interest as well... ['powershell MySQL'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20MySQL&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20mysql&sc=8-16&sk=&cvid=482BAB8A21C74925A0D83408D8F87BCA)   
['powershell Excel pivot table'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20Excel%20pivot%20table&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20excel%20pivot%20table&sc=3-28&sk=&cvid=98879BD23FBD40589430C8A69E6469D9) There are modules you can install in oder to work with MySQL and Excel.   [Find-Module -Name '*MySql*', '*Excel*' | Format-Table -AutoSize]

Comment: I'll check them out. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: No worries.....